# Determine the Topology induced by a discrete metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given the discrete metric below, determine the topology(s) induced by $d(x,y)$.

$$d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if } x=y\\
1,&\text{if } x \ne y\\
\end{cases}
$$
**Edit**
No attempt is given here as the hint that I needed to understand what confused me is already now given below! Thanks!

Comment: What does the topology generated by singletons look like? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in X$ what do the open balls $B(x,r)=\{y\in X; d(x,y)<r\}$ for positive real $r$ look like? What happens for $r\lt1$? How do they look like if $r\ge1$?

> You should see that if $r<1$, then $B(x,r)=\{x\}$, i.e., it is a singleton. If $r\ge1$ then $B(x,r)=X$, i.e., in this case the open ball is the whole space.

After you answer this question, it only remains to compare the basis that generate the two topologies.

Comment: I bet , I didn't get your point sir... please give us clear answer.thanx

Comment: @OmidSafarzadeh Can you say what $B(x,1)$ is? (I suppose that you defined the topology induced by a metric using open balls.)

Comment: B(x,1) is a ball with radius less than one sir

Comment: @OmidSafarzadeh That's true. But what is $B(x,1)$ equal for the metric you defined in your post? And what about $B(x,r)$ for any positive $r<1$.